# Modify the object without using return in R function

Tags: r

I am trying to reverse a string without using extra space in R. Below is the code for the same. My question is how to get the `ReverseString` function change the input without using extra space. I even tried using `<<-` without any luck.

```
ReverseString <- function(TestString){
  TestString <- unlist(strsplit(TestString, ""))
  Left <- 1
  Right <- length(TestString)
  while (Left < Right){
    Temp <- TestString[Left]
    TestString[Left] <- TestString[Right]
    TestString[Right] <- Temp
    Left <- Left + 1
    Right <- Right - 1
  }
  return(paste(TestString, collapse = ""))

}
## Input
a = "StackOverFlow"
## OutPut
ReverseString(a)
"wolFrevOkcatS"
## 
a
"StackOverFlow"
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "without using extra space in R"? Runing your code a then `ls()` gives me `"a" "ReverseString"`. So there is no extra object that was created.

Comment: Building your own function without using built-in functions is in my opinion too broad because one could also argue `while` and `for` are built in functions. `strsplit`,`unlist` are also built-in functions.

Comment: @NelsonGon I think the OP means the **revearsal** should be done without using a built in function. Whatever the case, this should definitely be clarified in the question.

Comment: @gersht You are right. I meant revearsal should be done without using a built in function.

Comment: @JasonMathews I've come up with a couple answers that you might find useful. One forgoes reversing functions, but it does use a reverse sequence, e.g. `13:1`. If that's not allowed, I've also adapted your code to remove as much "extra space" usage as possible, no `Temp`, etc. I also explain why I think modifying global variables probably isn't quite as great of an idea as you might think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment you want to reverse the string without calling any function that does the reversal, i.e. no `rev` and co. Both of the solutions below do this.

I think you are also trying to modify global `a` from within the function, which is why you tried  `<<-`. I'm not sure why it didn't work for you, but you might have used it incorrectly.

You should know that using `<<-` alone does not mean that you are using less space. To really save space you would have to call or modify global `a` at each step in your function where you call or modify `TestString`. This would entail some combination of `assign`, `do.call`, `eval` and `parse` - not to mention all the `paste`ing you would have to do to access elements of `a` by integer position. Your function would end up bulky, nearly unreadable, and very likley less efficient due to the numerous function calls, despite having saved a negligible amount of space by not storing a copy of `a`. If you're dead set on creating such an abomination, then take a look at the functions I just listed and figure out how to use them.

Your energy would be better spent by improving upon you string-reversing function in other ways. For example, you can shorten it quite a bit by using a numerical sequence such as `13:1` in `sapply`:

```r
reverse_string <- function(string) {
    vec <- str_split(string, "")[[1]]
    paste(sapply(length(vec):1, function(i) vec[i]), collapse = "")
}

reverse_string("StackOverFlow")

#### OUTPUT ####

[1] "wolFrevOkcatS"
```

If your interviewers also have a problem with reverse sequences then here's another option that's closer to your original code, just a little cleaner. I also did my best to eliminate other areas where "extra space" was being used (indices stored in single vector, no more `Temp`):

```r
reverse_string2 <- function(string){
    vec <- str_split(string, "")[[1]]
    i_vec <- c(1, length(vec))

    while(i_vec[1] < i_vec[2]) {
        vec[i_vec] <- vec[c(i_vec[2], i_vec[1])]
        i_vec <- i_vec + c(1, -1)
    }

    paste(vec, collapse = "")
}

reverse_string2("StackOverFlow")

#### OUTPUT ####

[1] "wolFrevOkcatS"
```

Answer (score 4):

It is always better to take advantage of the vectorization in R (instead of for or while loops). So, in base-R, without any packages, it would be something like:

```
ReverseString <- function(x) {
  #splitstring splits every character, and rev reverses the order
  out <- rev(strsplit(x, split = '')[[1]])
  #paste to paste them together
  paste(out, collapse = '')
}

a <- "StackOverFlow"
ReverseString(a)
#[1] "wolFrevOkcatS"
```

Comment: I am trying to build my own function without using inbuilt functions.

Comment: There are no built-in funcitons here (I am translating built-in as external functions, because everything is built-in otherwise).  All of them are part of base-R. I understand that in some interviews they might want you to not use any external packages, but forcing you to use a for-loop or while loop wouldn't make sense in my opinion.

Comment: you are right. In one of my interview I used table command to get the frequency of words but they asked me if I can write the code using own functions and loops.

Comment: I think the point of these kinds of interview questions is to see how you approach computational problems. Anybody can can call the function `rev` to reverse the order of a vector. They want to see how you solve the issue with the simplest tools possible, i.e. loops and indices. Still, it seems more like a CS lab question than a proper interview question.

Comment: @gersht I understand it's not a great idea. I should have been more specific in my question. I am practicing these questions for my upcoming interviews.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done easily with `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
a <- "StackOverFlow"
stri_reverse(a)
#[1] "wolFrevOkcatS"
```

Comment: I know the inbuilt functions can be used. But I am preparing for interviews in which I'll be asked obviously to write the code from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood exactly the problem, but I think you're looking for a way to reverse the string object and automatically assign it to the original object without having to do `a <- ReverseString(a)` (assuming this is the reason why you tried using `<<-`). My solution to this is using `deparse(substitute())` to read the original variable name inside the function and `assign` (using `envir = .GlobalEnv`) to assign your result over the original variable.

```
ReverseString <- function(TestString){

  nm <- deparse(substitute(TestString))

  TestString <- unlist(strsplit(TestString, ""))
  Left <- 1
  Right <- length(TestString)
  while (Left < Right){
    Temp <- TestString[Left]
    TestString[Left] <- TestString[Right]
    TestString[Right] <- Temp
    Left <- Left + 1
    Right <- Right - 1
  }

  assign(nm, paste(TestString, collapse = ""), envir = .GlobalEnv)

}

## Input
a = "StackOverFlow"

ReverseString(a)

a
#[1] "wolFrevOkcatS"
```

Comment: I think this is closer to what the OP is looking for when they say they want to avoid "using extra space". The only problem is that it uses the same amount of space because a copy of `a` is still made, it's just that assignment happens inside the function instead of assigning the function output to `a`. However, this is more of a criticism of the premise of the question than of your solution.